# Error while compiling Angular6 project

Tags: html, css, angular, web, ng-build

This is the first time I try to build an Angular project, sorry if i don't understand everything very well.
I found on Google the command "ng build --prod" so I tried it.
At the beginning, everything looks ok until an error occure:

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'.
node_modules/ngx-carousel/src/ngx-carousel/ngx-carousel.component.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/fantomiald/Usekey/Deploiement/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.
```

I tried to find the solution on some forums but i didn't find anything that could help me. I hope you will be able to help me.

If you need some code's elements of my project, don't hesitate to tell me, i'm gonna send you it fast.

By the way, if i use the "ng serve" command, there is no error.

Thanks !

Comment: The easy solution would probably be to run `npm i --save rxjs-compat`. The package you are using seems to be using deprecated rxjs api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run this command:

`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`